# Miswired 3 way switch in basement

Tags: electrical

I posted a while ago about a supposed 3 way switch setup that wasn't working. I have more information and along the way a few questions.

Intro: I had half of my basement finished with a bed/bath about 7 years ago. Before this it was concrete. Now there's standard framing, drywall, baseboard heating and new electrical - there's a lot of outlets on the walls, and I told the main guy do it all to code. The electrical is on its own GFCI circuit. I don't know if any original electric was there.

There are two doors, one from the unfinished basement and one from the little hall by the bathroom on the finished side. One is n/s facing, the other e/w. By each door is a box for a light switch. The contractor installed what I thought was a 3 way, including a dimmer- lutron or Leviton or something.

I never stayed in this room so I can't tell you fully how functional the lights were, but since doing diy renovations in anticipation of renting the entire house out, I've been changing the ugly outlets for nicer ones, putting GFCI boxes in the two pronged, and fixing random stuff - e.g. one upstairs even had it's poles crossed.

As I switched out this supposed three way, I noticed it didn't fully function as one. Rather than walk you through everything I went through I'll describe what actually is. (Each light could turn on and off the lights, but only if they were the one that turned it on- a bad traveler set up I know: effectively a dual SP.)

It turns out that box A, where the dimmer is, received the hot. I know this because I used my no contact voltage tester.

Box b, having a switch designed for three way, only had two wires and a ground. I checked out what was sitting in the back of the box- looking for an unused traveller. I would the normal white wires for the load going back, and the ground, but also a loan black wire inside a wire nut. I thought, she, maybe it's that. After all, if the electrician was good, and he had a blank canvas (2 assumptions that may be false), shouldn't there be a spare traveler? There was no ceiling or light, only joists before this work so they could and should have run something, but now it would be hard.

It turns out that black wire in the nut in box b is actually permanently hot. Why would there be a constant hot wire sitting there unused? I didn't dare use it with anything.

I thought I'd test my intuition and connect the hot to the dimmer and test for voltage in the two (disconnected) travelers in the lutron. It turns out they both kept reading hot. I thought they'd alternate as I flipped the switch. I think this has more to do with how the voltage tester works. Why would they both register voltage? The sensitivity was set to low.

Then I connected them, one at a time. I tried various combinations. This is what I found.

Box a dimmer functions as a light on it's own with only two wires connected- the hot and the right other one, in which case box B never gets any power and is out of the picture.

If the two travelers of box A are set one way, the way I finally set it, then Box A always has power and can always turn on the light, but not necessarily turn it off, because it might be giving box B power and box b might be on. There are times both boxes. When B is powered and on and a is on (A is always powered) turn when I go to turn A off, it will flash and if i hold the switch in the middle like a see saw, it will stay off, otherwise due to B having power, it will keep the light on. I wanted to set it so B gets power when A is off so a person can turn the light on from the bathroom but it turns out B always gets power in this combination.

In another combination, I think all wires connected, B conditionally gets power. A is like a sub switch that controls if B gets power, yes or no, and then b can decide on or off. What's cool about this is each can turn the lights on or off, like a 3 way, but not so fast. Yes, killing A kills the lights but switching B doesn't switch them back on. It is more like a password or combination lock- mission: get power to end receptacle using sub switches. There's no point in setting that up.

So A sends B power when wired one way. It's basically like a pigtail. Each can always turn on, always provoke, it's like the Senate, it takes a majority vote to kill the power, so it's kind of the reverse of the combination game, if two switches are sending signal. The good news is if you turned a switch on with one, you can and should turn it off with the same one. Leave the same way you came and you'll be fine.

Box b, to recap, the black wire sometime was not, the yellow one never.

Box A
[image: box A]

Box B
[image: box b]

4 questions-
1 why did my voltage meter go off when for both of the travellers on the dimmer?
2 how is A always sending power to B? That's like a pigtail join, regardless which traveller is set? I tried a different brand of the same device and got the same result.
3 what is that permanent hot doing on box b?
4 why is it set up like this?

I think he also could have used bigger boxes because they're a little tight.

Comment: Three ways switches can be complicated and I need someone holding my hand to do them.  If done to code or not will need an expert.  It does seem not everything was done to code, but the inspector should have caught it.  It was inspected?  Box size is determined by the amount of certain wires/devices, bigger than needed is up to the installer to use, but nicer for you.  Code deals with minimums, but larger can be use.